# Overloading std::begin() and std::end() for non-arrays

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, overloading, using-declaration

Let's assume I have the following `Data` class:

```
struct Data {
   char foo[8];
   char bar;
};
```

and the following function, `my_algorithm`, which takes a pair of `char *` (similar to an STL algorithm):

```
void my_algorithm(char *first, char *last);
```

For `Data`'s `foo` data member, instead of calling `my_algorithm()` like this:

```
Data data;
my_algorithm(data.foo, data.foo + 8);
```

I can use the [`std::begin()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/begin) and [`std::end()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/end) convenience function templates:

```
my_algorithm(std::begin(data.foo), std::end(data.foo));
```

I would like to achieve something similar to `Data`'s `bar` data member. That is, instead of writing:

```
my_algorithm(&data.bar, &data.bar + 1);
```

I would like to write something like:

```
my_algorithm(begin(data.bar), end(data.bar));
```

Therefore, I've defined the two following ordinary (non-template) functions for this case:

```
char* begin(char& c) { return &c; }
char*   end(char& c) { return &c + 1; }
```

So that I would be able to write code like the following:

```
Data data;

using std::begin;
using std::end;

my_algorithm(begin(data.foo), end(data.foo)); // ok - std::begin()/std::end()
my_algorithm(begin(data.bar), end(data.bar)); // Error!!!
```

With the `using` declarations above I would have expected `std::begin()`/`std::end()` and `::begin()`/`::end()` to be in the same overload set, respectively. Since the functions `::begin()` and `::end()` are a perfect match for the latter call and they are not templates, I would have expected the last call to `my_algorithm()` to match them. However, the ordinary functions are not considered at all. As a result the compilation fails, because `std::begin()` and `std::end()` are not matches for the call.

Basically, the latter call acts as if I had written instead:

```
my_algorithm(begin<>(data.bar), end<>(data.bar));
```

That is, only the function templates (i.e., `std::begin()`/`std::end()`) are considered by the overload resolution process, not the ordinary functions (i.e., not `::begin()`/`::end()`).

It only works as expected, if I fully qualify the calls to `::begin()`/`::end()`:

```
my_algorithm(::begin(data.bar), ::end(data.bar));
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: If you want it to act like an array, make it an array :) `char bar[1];`. This doesn't *really* answer your question, but may help your specific case.

Comment: Can't duplicate on my machine or at https://ideone.com/8cTR5r.

Comment: What version are you using of what compiler and what C++ standard library?

Comment: @Justin "`using std::begin; using std::end;` enables ADL" is not correct.  ADL is enabled by using an unqualified name.  The `using` lets the unqualified name find the members of `namespace std`.  If you do this in a local scope, it hides globals, because local declarations always hide declarations in larger scopes.  One can write `using std::begin; using ::begin;` to consider both plus names found through ADL.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's get a complete, reproducible example:

```
#include <iterator>

char* begin(char& c) { return &c; }
char*   end(char& c) { return &c + 1; }

namespace ns {
    void my_algorithm(char *first, char *last);

    void my_function() {
        using std::begin;
        using std::end;

        char c = '0';
        my_algorithm(begin(c), end(c));
    }
}
```

When you make the unqualified call to `begin(c)` and `end(c)`, the compiler goes through the process of [unqualified name lookup](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/unqualified_lookup) (described on the [Argument-dependent lookup page of cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl)).

For regular unqualified name lookup, the process is roughly to start at the namespace you are currently in—`::ns` in this case—and only move out a namespace if you don't find the specific name.

If a function call is unqualified, as it is here with `begin(c)` and `end(c)`, [argument dependent lookup](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl) can occur, which finds free functions declared in the same namespace as the types of the functions' arguments, through the process of extending the overload set by finding "associated namespaces."

In this case, however, `char` is a fundamental type, so argument dependent lookup doesn't allow us to find the global `::begin` and `::end` functions.

> For arguments of fundamental type, the associated set of namespaces and classes is empty

<sup>[cppreference: argument dependent lookup](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl)</sup>

Instead, as we already have `using std::begin; using std::end;`, the compiler already sees possible functions for `begin(...)` and `end(...)`—namely those defined in namespace `::std`—without having to move out a namespace from `::ns` to `::`. Thus, the compiler uses those functions, and compilation fails.

---

It's worth noting that the `using std::begin; using std::end;` also block the compiler from finding the custom `::begin` and `::end` even if you were to place them inside `::ns`.

---

What you can do instead is write your own `begin` and `end`:

```
#include <iterator>

namespace ns {
    char* begin(char& c) { return &c; }
    char*   end(char& c) { return &c + 1; }

    template <typename T>
    auto begin(T&& t) {
        using std::begin;
        // Not unbounded recursion if there's no `std::begin(t)`
        // or ADL `begin(t)`, for the same reason that our
        // char* begin(char& c); overload isn't found with
        // using std::begin; begin(c);
        return begin(t);
    }

    template <typename T>
    auto end(T&& t) {
        using std::end;
        return end(t);
    }

    void my_algorithm(char *first, char *last);

    void my_function() {
        char c = '0';
        my_algorithm(ns::begin(c), ns::end(c));
    }
}
```

Comment: I assumed fundamental types included the global namespace but now that I actually read that part, it explicitly doesn't pull in anything : "For arguments of fundamental type, the associated set of namespaces and classes is empty".

Comment: Great answer! Just for clarification: The `using` directive doesn't block *ADL*, does it? Otherwise, the `using std::swap;` trick for using `std::swap()` as a fallback for `swap()` when there is no such a function in the enclosing namespace of the class of the objects to swap couldn't work, right?

Comment: @ElProfesor No, it doesn't block ADL.

Comment: @ElProfesor ADL has no impact.

Comment: So verbose that it's difficult to say what this answer about. Long story about ADL and conclusion that ADL does not matters here. Another answer is clear. Why you need such helpers...

Comment: Other (better?) solution 1: `namespace std_iterators { using std::begin; using std::end; }` and inside a function `using namespace std_iterators` instead of `using std::begin; using std::end;` ([link](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e4e7d333ffe137e8)). Solution 2: same as before but turn `std_iterators` into an unnamed namespace - `std::begin` and `std::end` would be "globally" available for every function without the need of `using` directive ([link](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/751209095e510a88)).

Answer (score -4):

The title of question is "**Overloading std**::begin()". Overloading is possible only within the same scope. That is you can't overload names from different scopes. In another scope we can only make efforts to help lookup name. Essentially, here **"using std::begin" declaration hides** ::begin in question's code. See S.Lippman for reference:

> functions that are members of two distinct namespaces do not overload one another.
>
> Scope of a using Declaration. Names introduced in a using declaration obey normal scope rules.
>   Entities with the same name defined in an outer scope are hidden.

As soon as parameter is char and char is fundamental type - argument dependent lookup should not be taken into consideration - as mentioned in comments - there is no associated namespace with fundamental types. 
  Again, the question was: "What am I missing?" - therefore the answer is focused only on reasons - recommendations may be too broad.

Comment: No, there's [argument dependent lookup](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl) which allows several namespaces to be considered for overloads based on the arguments.

Comment: @François Andrieux You are wrong - I didn't say about lookup. Lippman C++ primer: "each namespace maintains its own scope. As a consequence, functions that are members of two distinct namespaces do not overload one another"

Comment: You're right that the names don't overload each other, but they are both considered during overload resolution. Meaning that the fact that they aren't technically overloads of each other isn't the answer to this question.  If it *is* the answer to this question, you'll need to clarify how because I missed it. Edit : From the other answer it seems the free functions at the global namespace doesn't qualify.

Comment: TS tries to overload names from std and global namespace - I indicated that this is mistake. Yes, lookup resolution may find name in outer scope - but this is not what TS wants - not overloading. using may lift names in outer namespace - but this is not overloading.